# Attack of 3-methylbutan-1-ol on benzene in acidic medium

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, erratum, electrophilic-substitution

[image]

That's how I proceeded with the question. However the answer is *tert*-butylbenzene. I can't figure out why do I have an extra carbon atom.

**SOURCE**
- JEE Advanced 1994

Comment: Yes, your mechanism seems quite correct. I believe it must be a printing error

Comment: I agree. No way can you get t-Bu Benzene from this sytem.

Comment: I feel like dehydration of the alcohol is going to be much more likely under the forcing conditions whereby you might actually generate that primary cation...

Comment: Benzene, the nucleophile, attacks the alcohol - as the cation - which is the electrophile. ;)

Comment: The original question doesn't have an extra carbon.